# MySQL: How to remove duplicate records or check for duplicate when insert?

Tags: mysql, sql

I know there are many answers indicated using rank() or row_number(), however, they are not supported in SQL-FRONT or Navicat, I tried Microsoft SSMS but it didnot support my sql. I tried many methods, didn't work. So I'm hopeless now.

Table is shown below, I just want to know how to remove duplicate records with the same name and time. Thank you.

[image: a simple table shown in the link]

Comment: You should have shown what you tried and how it failed. I have posted an answer. I hope it's nothing you've already tried in vain.

Comment: Do you need to insert new record on duplicate OR just check the duplicate and discard the upcoming data???

Answer (score 1):

Use an `EXISTS` clause to find duplicates.

```
delete from mytable
where exists
(
  select *
  from mytable other
  where other.name = mytable.name
  and other.time = mytable.time
  and other.id < mytable.id
);
```

As for inserts: Place a unique constraint on the two columns. This is usually done with a unique index:

```
create unique index idx_unique_name_time on mytable (name, time);
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can use `join` and aggregation:

```
delete t
     from t join
          (select name, time, min(id) as min_id
           from t
           group by name, time
          ) tt
          on t.name = tt.name and t.time = tt.time and
             t.id > tt.min_id;
```